# Cant access $id in redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason im not able to access $id when im trying to redirect after i submit my form. I can access $id outside the if statement but it seems i get the redirect with an empty value of $id. Any suggestion?

```
   function edit_user($id = NULL){

    if(!$id)
    {
        show_404();            
    }

    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Nombre de usuario','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Contraseña','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkpassword','Reingrese contraseña','required|matches[password]');          

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required','El Campo %s es obligatorio');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('matches','Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden');

        if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE){

        $this->Users_model->edit_users();
        $mensaje = "Usuario editado correctamente";

        redirect(base_url().'users/edit_user/'.$id,  301);

        }
        else
        {

            redirect(base_url().'users/edit_user/'.$id,  301);

        }

    }

    $query = $this->Users_model->getuserid($id);

        if($query == false){

            $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                                       'content'=>'users/add_users_view',
                            'id'=>$id);
            }else{

                $data = array('title'=>'Admin ::LxFPanamá::',
                            'content'=>'users/edit_users_view',
                            'id'=> $query->id,
                            'login'=> $query->login,
                            'password'=> $query->password);
            }

    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->config->item('theme_front').'.php', $data);
}
```

Comment: Are you positive you are getting the `$id` outside of the if? What have you done to verify this?

Comment: Just a note, if you're using the latest version of CI and haven't modified the redirect function, the 301 in your redirects should be the 3rd parameter, not the 2nd.

Comment: if i print $id doing echo $id; outside the statement it works

Comment: try, redirect('users/edit_user/'.$id);

Comment: try to replace if(!$id) by if((int)$id!=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `flashdata`

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item',$i);
redirect(base_url().'users/edit_user','refresh',301);
```

to get the value back

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```